# SQL FIFO query with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables:

```
INVENTORY_IN:

        ID INV_TIMESTAMP     PRODUCT_ID IN_QUANTITY SUPPLIER_ID
        ...
         1 10.03.21 01:00:00        101         100           4
         2 11.03.21 02:00:00        101          50           3
         3 14.03.21 01:00:00        101          10           2

INVENTORY_OUT:

        ID INV_TIMESTAMP     PRODUCT_ID OUT_QUANTITY CUSTOMER_ID
        ...
         1 10.03.21 02:00:00        101           30           1
         2 11.03.21 01:00:00        101           40           2
         3 12.03.21 01:00:00        101           80           1

INVENTORY_BALANCE:

    INV_DATE PRODUCT_ID   QUANTITY
    ...
    09.03.21        101         20
    10.03.21        101         90
    11.03.21        101        100
    12.03.21        101         20
    13.03.21        101         20
    14.03.21        101         30
```

I want to use FIFO (first in-first out) logic for the inventory, and to see which quantities correspond to each SUPPLIER-CUSTOMER combination.
**The desired ouput looks like this** (queried for dates >= 2021-03-10):

```
PRODUCT_ID SUPPLIER_ID CUSTOMER_ID   QUANTITY

       101                       1         20
       101           4           1         60
       101           4           2         40
       101           3           1         30
       101           3                     20
       101           2                     10
```

edit. fixed little typo in numbers.

[image: diagram]
edit. Added a diagram which explains every row. All of the black arrows correspond to supplier and customer combinations, there are 7 of them, because for supplier_id = 4 and customer_id = 1 the desired results is the sum of matched quantities happening between them. So, it explains why there are 7 arrows, while the desired results contains only 6 rows.

Comment: Please explain how the quantity in result has been calculated.

Comment: Hi. The initial inventory had 20 items. According to FIFO logic, it was sold first on 10.03.21 02:00:00 to customer_id = 1. But, customer_id = 1 bought 30 items total, therefore, 10 (30-20) items he purchased were from the quantity that entered inventory on 10.03.21 01:00:00. Proceding this logic we can calculate all numbers in the desired output pan.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a complete worked example where you tell us the logic of how each number of your expected output is calculated at each step with an explanation in plain English (not code).

Comment: Added a diagram which basically explains every row of the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

This is probably a job for PL/SQL. Starting with the data types to output:

```sql
CREATE TYPE supply_details_obj AS OBJECT(
  product_id  NUMBER,
  quantity    NUMBER,
  supplier_id NUMBER,
  customer_id NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE supply_details_tab AS TABLE OF supply_details_obj;
```

Then we can define a pipelined function to read the `INVENTORY_IN` and `INVENTORY_OUT` tables one row at a time and merge the two keeping a running total of the remaining inventory or amount to supply:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION assign_suppliers_to_customers (
  i_product_id IN INVENTORY_IN.PRODUCT_ID%TYPE
)
RETURN supply_details_tab PIPELINED
IS
  v_supplier_id  INVENTORY_IN.SUPPLIER_ID%TYPE;
  v_customer_id  INVENTORY_OUT.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE;
  v_quantity_in  INVENTORY_IN.IN_QUANTITY%TYPE   := NULL;
  v_quantity_out INVENTORY_OUT.OUT_QUANTITY%TYPE := NULL;
  v_cur_in       SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_cur_out      SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur_in FOR
    SELECT in_quantity, supplier_id
    FROM   INVENTORY_IN
    WHERE  product_id = i_product_id
    ORDER BY inv_timestamp;

  OPEN v_cur_out FOR
    SELECT out_quantity, customer_id
    FROM   INVENTORY_OUT
    WHERE  product_id = i_product_id
    ORDER BY inv_timestamp;

  LOOP
    IF v_quantity_in IS NULL THEN
      FETCH v_cur_in INTO v_quantity_in, v_supplier_id;
      IF v_cur_in%NOTFOUND THEN
        v_supplier_id := NULL;
      END IF;
    END IF;
    IF v_quantity_out IS NULL THEN
      FETCH v_cur_out INTO v_quantity_out, v_customer_id;
      IF v_cur_out%NOTFOUND THEN
        v_customer_id := NULL;
      END IF;
    END IF;

    EXIT WHEN v_cur_in%NOTFOUND AND v_cur_out%NOTFOUND;

    IF v_quantity_in > v_quantity_out THEN
      PIPE ROW(
        supply_details_obj(
          i_product_id,
          v_quantity_out,
          v_supplier_id,
          v_customer_id
        )
      );
      v_quantity_in  := v_quantity_in - v_quantity_out;
      v_quantity_out := NULL;
    ELSE
      PIPE ROW(
        supply_details_obj(
          i_product_id,
          v_quantity_in,
          v_supplier_id,
          v_customer_id
        )
      );
      v_quantity_out := v_quantity_out - v_quantity_in;
      v_quantity_in  := NULL;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY_IN ( ID, INV_TIMESTAMP, PRODUCT_ID, IN_QUANTITY, SUPPLIER_ID ) AS
SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-09 00:00:00', 101,  20, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-10 01:00:00', 101, 100, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-11 02:00:00', 101,  50, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-14 01:00:00', 101,  10, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE INVENTORY_OUT ( ID, INV_TIMESTAMP, PRODUCT_ID, OUT_QUANTITY, CUSTOMER_ID ) AS
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-10 02:00:00', 101, 30, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-11 01:00:00', 101, 40, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-12 01:00:00', 101, 80, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

The query:

```sql
SELECT product_id,
       supplier_id,
       customer_id,
       SUM( quantity ) AS quantity
FROM   TABLE( assign_suppliers_to_customers( 101 ) )
GROUP BY
       product_id,
       supplier_id,
       customer_id
ORDER BY
       MIN( inv_timestamp )
```

Outputs:

> ```
> PRODUCT_ID | SUPPLIER_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | QUANTITY
> ---------: | ----------: | ----------: | -------:
>        101 |           0 |           1 |       20
>        101 |           4 |           1 |       60
>        101 |           4 |           2 |       40
>        101 |           3 |           1 |       30
>        101 |           3 |        null |       20
>        101 |           2 |        null |       10
> ```

---

## Option 2

A (very) complicated SQL query:

```sql
WITH in_totals ( ID, INV_TIMESTAMP, PRODUCT_ID, IN_QUANTITY, SUPPLIER_ID, TOTAL_QUANTITY ) AS (
  SELECT i.*,
         SUM( in_quantity ) OVER ( PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY inv_timestamp )
  FROM   inventory_in i
),
out_totals ( ID, INV_TIMESTAMP, PRODUCT_ID, OUT_QUANTITY, CUSTOMER_ID, TOTAL_QUANTITY ) AS (
  SELECT o.*,
         SUM( out_quantity ) OVER ( PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY inv_timestamp )
  FROM   inventory_out o
),
split_totals ( product_id, inv_timestamp, supplier_id, customer_id, quantity ) AS (
  SELECT i.product_id,
         MIN( COALESCE( LEAST( i.inv_timestamp, o.inv_timestamp ), i.inv_timestamp ) )
           AS inv_timestamp,
         i.supplier_id,
         o.customer_id,
         SUM(
           COALESCE(
             LEAST(
               i.total_quantity - o.total_quantity + o.out_quantity,
               o.total_quantity - i.total_quantity + i.in_quantity,
               i.in_quantity,
               o.out_quantity
             ),
             0
           )
         )
  FROM   in_totals i
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         out_totals o
         ON (   i.product_id = o.product_id
            AND i.total_quantity - i.in_quantity <= o.total_quantity
            AND i.total_quantity >= o.total_quantity - o.out_quantity )
  GROUP BY
         i.product_id,
         i.supplier_id,
         o.customer_id
  ORDER BY
         inv_timestamp
),
missing_totals ( product_id, inv_timestamp, supplier_id, customer_id, quantity ) AS (
  SELECT i.product_id,
         i.inv_timestamp,
         i.supplier_id,
         NULL,
         i.in_quantity - COALESCE( s.quantity, 0 )
  FROM   inventory_in i
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT product_id,
                  supplier_id,
                  SUM( quantity ) AS quantity
           FROM   split_totals
           GROUP BY product_id, supplier_id
         ) s
         ON (   i.product_id = s.product_id
            AND i.supplier_id = s.supplier_id )
  ORDER BY i.inv_timestamp
)
SELECT product_id, supplier_id, customer_id, quantity
FROM   (
  SELECT product_id, inv_timestamp, supplier_id, customer_id, quantity
  FROM   split_totals
  WHERE  quantity > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT product_id, inv_timestamp, supplier_id, customer_id, quantity
  FROM   missing_totals
  WHERE  quantity > 0
  ORDER BY inv_timestamp
);
```

Which, for the sample data above, outputs:

> ```
> PRODUCT_ID | SUPPLIER_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | QUANTITY
> ---------: | ----------: | ----------: | -------:
>        101 |           0 |           1 |       20
>        101 |           4 |           1 |       60
>        101 |           4 |           2 |       40
>        101 |           3 |           1 |       30
>        101 |           3 |        null |       20
>        101 |           2 |        null |       10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b1175e069dd79263c8b5a2ef08488e4f)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. But I dont think this solves the issue. The sum here is the inventory balance, and the supplier_id and customer_id are the last that happened for a transaction.

Comment: @4yz That is what this gives you.

Comment: Moreover, if we sum for supplier_id = 4, it will result in quantity = 200, but the supplier_id = 4 only added 100. And the desired results are obviously not replicated here.

Comment: @4yz Your expected output does not sum to 100 for `supplier_id = 4`. How are we meant to generate something when you have not told us how the query is expected to work and if your expected output does not match your expectations?

Comment: Yes, just saw that, I have badly messed up with the numbers being in a hurry, I will fix it now.

Comment: Fixed the desired results. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @4yz Updated, but you need to have the starting 20 in the `INVENTORY_IN` table (which I am assuming that you have, it is just outside the range you are showing in the question).

Comment: The number 20 is shown in the inventory_balance table for 2021-03-09 (prior to in's and out's). Yes, I can assume its already in the transactional tables, but it still doesnt give me a desired output. I have added a diagram, and I think it will be helpful.

Comment: @4yz Updated again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the algorithm works well. Is is possible to workaround it somehow using SQL rather than using PL/SQL'ish objects using some kind of recursive cte's with conditions?

Comment: You've added this while I was writing the query) SQL approach is really good and portable. I've used this pattern of distribution a lot of times in DWH projects with different SQL dialects. So just need to identify that it is applicable to the task.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MT0. I will go through it to make sure I understand it properly.

Comment: @MT0, How do you think, is it theoretically feasible to make a chainwise structure of it. So the flow of inventory will be like the following: supplier -> warehouse1 -> warehouse2->store -> customer. Those will be dimensions, and metric will be the quantity again. Not asking this as a separate question, because I am interested in your personal opinion rather that a very well thought answer, or a solution, since you probably worked with such kind of structures.

Comment: And of course, allowing for cases which miss some "stages" such as :supplier -> warehouse1 -> customer

Answer (score 0):

If your system controls the timestamps so you cannot consume what was not supplied (I've met systems, that didn't track intraday balance), then you can use SQL solution with interval join. The only thing to take care here is to track the last supply that was not consumed in full: it should be added as supply with no customer.

Here's the query with comments:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE INVENTORY_IN ( ID, INV_TIMESTAMP, PRODUCT_ID, IN_QUANTITY, SUPPLIER_ID ) AS
> SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-09 00:00:00', 101,  20, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-10 01:00:00', 101, 100, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-11 02:00:00', 101,  50, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-14 01:00:00', 101,  10, 2 FROM DUAL;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE INVENTORY_OUT ( ID, INV_TIMESTAMP, PRODUCT_ID, OUT_QUANTITY, CUSTOMER_ID ) AS
> SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-10 02:00:00', 101, 30, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-11 01:00:00', 101, 40, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '2021-03-12 01:00:00', 101, 80, 1 FROM DUAL;
> ```

> ```
> with i as (
>   select
>     /*Get total per product, supplier at each timestamp
>       to calculate running sum on timestamps without need to resolve ties with over(... rows between) addition*/
>     inv_timestamp
>     , product_id
>     , supplier_id
>     , sum(in_quantity) as quan
>     , sum(sum(in_quantity)) over(
>         partition by product_id
>           
>         order by
>           inv_timestamp asc
>           , supplier_id asc
>       ) as rsum
>   from INVENTORY_IN
>   group by
>     product_id
>     , supplier_id
>     , inv_timestamp
> )
> , o as (
>   select /*The same for customer*/
>     inv_timestamp
>     , product_id
>     , customer_id
>     , sum(out_quantity) as quan
>     , sum(sum(out_quantity)) over(
>         partition by product_id
>           
>         order by
>           inv_timestamp asc
>           , customer_id asc
>       ) as rsum
>     /*Last consumption per product: when lead goes beyond the current window*/
>     , lead(0, 1, 1) over(
>         partition by product_id
>         order by 
>           inv_timestamp asc
>           , customer_id asc
>     ) as last_consumption
>   from INVENTORY_OUT
>   group by
>     product_id
>     , customer_id
>     , inv_timestamp
> )
> , distr as (
> select
>   /*Distribute the quantity. This is the basic interval intersection:
>     new_value_to = least(t1.value_to, t2.value_to)
>     new_value_from = greatest(t1.value_from, t2.value_from)
>     
>     So we need a capacity of the interval
>   */
>   i.product_id
>   , least(i.rsum, nvl(o.rsum, i.rsum))
>     - greatest(i.rsum - i.quan, nvl(o.rsum - o.quan, i.rsum - i.quan)) as supplied_quan
>   /*At the last supply we can have something not used.
>     Calculate it to add later as not consumed
>   */
>   , case
>       when last_consumption = 1
>         and i.rsum > nvl(o.rsum, i.rsum)
>       then i.rsum - o.rsum
>     end as rest_quan
>   , i.supplier_id
>   , o.customer_id
>   , i.inv_timestamp as i_ts
>   , o.inv_timestamp as o_ts
> from i
>   left join o
>     on i.product_id = o.product_id
>      /*No equality here, because values are continuous:
>      >= will include the same value in two intervals if some of value_to of one table equals
>      another's table value_to (which is value_from for the next interval)*/
>       and i.rsum > o.rsum - o.quan
>       and o.rsum > i.rsum - i.quan
> )
> select
>   product_id
>   , supplier_id
>   , customer_id
>   , sum(quan) as quan
> from (
>   select /*Get distributed quantities*/
>     product_id
>     , supplier_id
>     , customer_id
>     , supplied_quan as quan
>     , i_ts
>     , o_ts
>   from distr
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select /*Add not consumed part of last consumed supply*/
>     product_id
>     , supplier_id
>     , null
>     , rest_quan
>     , i_ts
>     , null /*No consumption*/
>   from distr
>   where rest_quan is not null
> )
> group by
>   product_id
>   , supplier_id
>   , customer_id
> order by
>   min(i_ts) asc
>   /*To order not consumed last*/
>   , min(o_ts) asc nulls last
> ```

> ```
> PRODUCT_ID | SUPPLIER_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | QUAN
> ---------: | ----------: | ----------: | ---:
>        101 |           0 |           1 |   20
>        101 |           4 |           1 |   60
>        101 |           4 |           2 |   40
>        101 |           3 |           1 |   30
>        101 |           3 |        null |   20
>        101 |           2 |        null |   10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a32f8ad43a8fb80ad537aa6df68f72ea)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go through it to make sure I understand it properly.

Comment: How do you think, is it theoretically feasible to make a chainwise structure of it. So the flow of inventory will be like the following: supplier -> warehouse1 -> warehouse2->store -> customer. Those will be dimensions, and metric will be the quantity again. Not asking this as a separate question, because I am interested in your personal opinion rather that a very well thought answer, or a solution, since you probably worked with such kind of structures.

Comment: And of course, allowing for cases which miss some "stages" such as :supplier -> warehouse1 -> customer

Comment: @4yz Yes, the pattern is the same: 1) determine quantity intervals, 2) do interval join, get the intersected quantity, 3) add not distributed with no corresponding party. But you'll need to keep timestamps for later use for running sum. At each new step you'll use your distributed quantity as a basis for running sums at building quantity intervals. At last step aggregate on all the keys of interest. This way you'll keep not distributed quantities as not assigned to next consumer and they will not participate in the distribution (nulls will not be joined, so quantity will be simply propagated)

Comment: @4yz If your data is synchronized well, this will work fine. Also complex ordering can be managed (e.g you can have some extra columns to prioritize next  consumer, then you'll add them into `order by` of running sum and also in `group by` to have distinct running sum at each row). We've used this pattern in demand -> plan -> procure -> supply chain and it was good (with some complexities of batching to lower logistics costs or in case of some packaging limitations, where you sometimes procure more than requested).