# Query for Order fulfillment available date

Tags: sql, sql-server

*** UPDATE *** Code is added below.

I need to calculate and get inventory available date for each Sales Order(SO).  Each SO fulfillment is based on first-in-first-fulfill.  Fulfillment is based on currently available inventory with purchase (PO) quantity and PO arrival date.  For example:

Current inventory quantity: 100 ea

PO quantity and available date is:

```
PO#1:  30 ea, available date 2021-06-01
PO#2:  40 ea, available date 2021-06-15
PO#3:  30 ea, available date 2021-07-25
PO#4: 100 ea, available date 2021-08-20
```

SO required quantity is below:

```
SO#1: 80 ea
SO#2: 30 ea
SO#3: 10 ea
SO#4: 30 ea
SO#5: 110 ea
SO#6: 100 ea
```

Need to write a SQL to assign each SO available date, and expected query availability date result is below.

```
SO#1 - available date NOW (80 ea from inventory)
SO#2 - available date 2021-06-01 (20 ea from inventory and 10 ea from PO#1.  SO available date is PO#1 date)
SO#3 - available date 2021-06-01 (10 ea from PO#1.  SO available date is PO#1 date)
SO#4 - available date 2021-06-15 (10 ea from PO#1. 20 ea from PO#2.  SO available date is PO#2 date)
SO#5 - available date 2021-08-20 (20 ea from PO#2. 30 ea from PO#3. 60 ea from PO#4.  SO available date is PO#4 date)
SO#6 - available date N.A. (40 ea from PO#4, no more PO and not enough to fulfill SO#6)
```

Followed Gordon Linoff's comments, I wrote code below.  But, I cannot make it work by Gordon Linoff's LEFT LINK solution.  I use MIN(ETA) to get result.  It is correct.  Will it have more neat solution?

```
CREATE TABLE PO (
PONo VARCHAR(50),
Quantity INT,
ETA DATE)

CREATE TABLE SO (
SONo VARCHAR(50),
Quantity INT,
FillDate DATE)

INSERT INTO PO (PONo, Quantity, ETA) VALUES
('PO0',100, '2021-05-17'),
('PO1',30, '2021-06-01'),
('PO2',40, '2021-06-15'),
('PO3',30, '2021-07-25'),
('PO4',100,'2021-08-20')

INSERT INTO SO (SONo, Quantity) VALUES
('SO1',80),
('SO2',30),
('SO3',10),
('SO4',30),
('SO5',110),
('SO6',100)


SELECT SONo, Quantity, MIN(ETA) SOAvailDate FROM (
SELECT SO.SoNo, SO.Quantity, PO.PONo, PO.ETA FROM 
(SELECT SO.*, SUM(Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY SO.SONo) as SORunning  FROM SO) AS SO
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT PO.*, SUM(Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY PO.PONo) as PORunning  FROM PO) AS PO
ON SO.SORunning <= PO.PORunning ) AS A
GROUP BY SONO, Quantity
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output as proper tables and columns (preferably `CREATE/INSERT` statements) would help immensely. It looks like you need a cumulative sum over POs and SOs, and then match them up based on those sums

Comment: I feel I've seen similar question not so long ago. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660928/sql-fifo-query-with-group-by/66664829#66664829)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code provides the result I need.

```
SELECT SO.SONo, SO.Quantity, PO.PONo, PO.ETA, PO.ETA FulfillDate FROM 
(SELECT SO.*, SUM(Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY SO.SONo) as SORunning  FROM SO) AS SO
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT PO.*, SUM(Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY PO.PONo) as PORunning  FROM PO) AS PO
ON
PO.PORunning - PO.Quantity < SO.SORunning 
AND PO.PORunning >= SO.SORunning - SO.Quantity
AND SO.SORunning <= PO.PORunning
```

Result:

```
SONo    Quantity    PONo    ETA         FulfillDate
SO1     80          PO0     2021-05-17  2021-05-17
SO2     30          PO1     2021-06-01  2021-06-01
SO3     10          PO1     2021-06-01  2021-06-01
SO4     30          PO2     2021-06-15  2021-06-15
SO5     110         PO4     2021-08-20  2021-08-20
SO6     100         NULL    NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to this question is the cumulative sum . . . and `join`.  The following returns a list of all POs needed for each SO:

```
select so.*, po.*
from (select so.*, sum(qty) over (order by so.so_num) as running_qty
      from so
     ) so left join
     (select po.*, sum(qty) over (order by po.po_num) as running_qty
      from po
     ) po
     on po.running_qty - qty < so.running_qty  and
        po.running_qty >= so.running_qty - qty
```

If you then want this summarized by so, you can do:

```
select so.so_num, so.qty, max(po.date), string_agg(po.po_num, ',') as po_nums
from (select so.*, sum(qty) over (order by so.so_num) as running_qty
      from so
     ) so left join
     (select po.*, sum(qty) over (order by po.po_num) as running_qty
      from po
     ) po
     on po.running_qty - qty < so.running_qty  and
        po.running_qty >= so.running_qty - qty
group by so.so_num, so.qty;
```

Comment: Wrote code to test.  Revise Question to include code.  Not sure how to use LEFT JOIN ON "po.running_qty - qty < so.running_qty  and po.running_qty >= so.running_qty - qty"